# Regular expression to convert string another string powershell

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I have a string as given below

```
$mystring="t={p:1,q:2,r:3}"
```

i want to convert this string to a following string

```
"t={'p':'1','q':'2','r':'3'}"
```

How can i do this in powershell

Code i tried is given below

```
$list=[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($mystring,"[{:,]").Value
foreach($dicitem in $diclist)
{
$dic=$dic.Replace("$dicitem","$dicitem'")
}
$list=[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($dic,"[}:,]").Value
foreach($dicitem in $diclist)
{
$dic=$dic.Replace("$dicitem","'$dicitem")
}
```

But iam not getting the result as expected,is there any other better way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -replace operator is much easier.  This solution uses backreferences instead of the -f format operator.

Edit: misread the question originally (missed that the letters needed to be quoted, too.
Update solution:

```
$mystring="t={p:1,q:2,r:3}"
$mystring -replace '([^{,]+):([^,}])+',"'`$1':'`$2'"

t={'p':'1','q':'2','r':'3'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$mystring -replace '(?<={.*)([a-z])|\d',("'{0}'" -f '$0')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
$mystring -replace '(?<={.*)([^:,}])', ("'{0}'" -f '$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a regex replace. Search for Regex:

```
(?<!\})(?!.*\{)
```

And replace with single quote `'`

Explanation of the regex:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \}                       '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \{                       '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```